# Getting duplicates while trying to sum accumulated values

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I'm trying to sum accumulated values but I get duplicates. This is an example of my table

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 30 |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 30 |

My code right now is:

`select date, sum(value) over (partition by date) from table`

But I get this result:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 50 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 50 |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 30 |

What I would like to do is sum all values but also the values from dates before and get a table like this:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 70 |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 100 |

Any advice or idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below instead.

```sql
select date, sum(sum(value)) over (order by date) value
  from table
 group by date;

+---------------------+-------+
|        date         | value |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |    20 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |    70 |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 |   100 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

- `sum(sum(value)) over ()` - a window function (outer *sum()*) is evaluated after aggregation (inner *sum*()).